# Laravel query performance test

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I Have a messaging app, and for the function of checking if there are any new messages I decided to create a table apart from the messages table, where there is a simple flag for signaling if there is a new message inbox.

As the unread message flag table has less fields, and way less rows than the messages tables I thought it would be a more efficient choice than to search the whole message table for unread messages.

But the outcome when timing the two queries was the opposite. The option of searching the whole message table is performing faster. I can't figure out why, and maybe I know less about databases than I thought. The outcome makes no sense, can anyone find out whats going wrong?

timing script and queries:

```
 $start=hrtime(true);
        
        UnreadMessageFlagClient::query()
                                ->where('client_id',50)
                                ->get();
                                

        $end=hrtime(true);
        $eta=$end-$start;

        $time1 = $eta/1e+6;

        $start2=hrtime(true);
       
        Message::query()
                 ->where('talk_id',10)
                 ->where('sent_by','p')
                 ->whereNull('read_by_receiver')
                 ->get();

        $end2=hrtime(true);
        $eta2=$end2-$start2;

        $time2 = $eta2/1e+6;



        echo 'Time1: '.$time1.' <br/><br/> Time2: '.$time2;
```

The output is always higher with the first, like:

Time1: 3.794781

Time2: 1.475115

And the tables:

```
 Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('talk_id');
            $table->text('message', 6000);
            $table->string('sent_by',1); // C para cliente P para profissional
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

 Schema::create('unread_message_flag_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('client_id');
            $table->boolean('unread_messages_flag')->nullable();
        });
```

At the test moment messages table had 486 rows, and unread_message_flag_clients has 60

Comment: I'd use raw SQL for performance testing:  `explain` or even `explain analyze`. Maybe there's better indexing in `messages`.  Or turn  SQL `general_log` on – and see exactly what's going on with your queries time-wise

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and the generated SQL for each variant.  Those will help a lot in figuring out why the performance is the way it is -- and what to do about it.